# How do I integrate checkboxes with v-data-table - Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a simple V-data-table. I am trying to add checkboxes for each row in the table.

My table looks like this.

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="rows"item-key="name" :search="search">
    <template v-slot:item="props">
        <tr >
            <td v-for="(prop, key) in props.item" :key="key" @click="onClickItem(key, props.item[key])">
                {{props.item[key]}}     
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- Some icons for editing rows -->        
            </td>
        </tr>
    </template> 
    <template v-slot:top>
         <!-- A dialog box for editing rows -->
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

I tried to use the [official guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) for doing this, however all my rows get shifted to the right by 1 position & I only see only one checkbox even though I have multiple rows, that too, on the header!
How should I proceed?

Comment: Do you post your code with checkbox ?

Comment: you should give 'show-select' as a prop

Comment: @Rikkas I am a bit new to VueJs & Vuetify. Could you please explain how I could pass 'show-select' as a prop?

Comment: @HansFelixRamos I simply followed the documentation. Just added 'show-select' in the ```v-data-table``` tag

Comment: it should work then?

Comment: @Rikkas I am still facing the same issue mentioned above. Not really sure how I should proceed

Comment: looks like item slot is overwriting what your prop bring up. Just try to remove it or use it like item.whatsoever="{ props }

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working codepen similar to official doc
https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/MWadELG

another way
https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/bGVyoaw

TEMPLATE PART:

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
  <h5>Selected: {{selected}}</h5>
  <v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  item-key="name"
  show-select
  class="elevation-1"
  >
  </v-data-table>
 </v-app>
</div>
```

SCRIPT PART:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
vuetify: new Vuetify(),
data () {
return {
  singleSelect: false,
  selected: [],
  headers: [
    {
      text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
      align: 'start',
      sortable: false,
      value: 'name',
    },
    { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
    { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
    { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
    { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
    { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
  ],
  desserts: [
    {
      name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
      calories: 159,
      fat: 6.0,
      carbs: 24,
      protein: 4.0,
      iron: '1%',
    },
    {
      name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
      calories: 237,
      fat: 9.0,
      carbs: 37,
      protein: 4.3,
      iron: '1%',
    },
    {
      name: 'Eclair',
      calories: 262,
      fat: 16.0,
      carbs: 23,
      protein: 6.0,
      iron: '7%',
    },
  ],
 }
},
})
```

Comment: Hey Manoj, Thanks for your answer. As you could see in the question section, I have a different table. I am using props.

Comment: Thanks Sameer, understood now. Also, in case you are using ( <td v-for="(prop, key) in props.item" :key="key" @click="onClickItem(key, props.item[key])">
{{props.item[key]}}  </td>) to track the item clicked, you can use  <v-data-table ....... @click:row="handleClick">  , it will return object with row data which can be filtered as per required column value. For editing row icons separate templates can be added. In this way checkboxes will not break and v-data-table functionality will also be more intact.

Comment: How to set it a default value as checked in that example??